# Binary matrix in R: how to turn all 1 to 0 if they lie within N-steps of original zero

Tags: r, matrix

I apologise for the title, it will probably improve with suggestions.

I need to edit a binary matrix in R so that where ever there was a zero, I  turn all surrounding entries to zero (if not zero already), if they lie within N steps of the original zero. The path can be L-shaped or straight, including diagonal, and diagonal path followed by straight path, as long as they are continuous unbroken paths.

So if N=2, the effect would be to expand the one zero in my example into a cloud of zeros, like this
original matrix:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
 [2,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
 [3,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
 [4,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    0    1    1     1
 [5,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
 [6,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
 [7,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
 [8,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
 [9,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
[10,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
```

with N=2 becomes

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
 [2,]    1    1    1    1    0    1    0    1    0     1
 [3,]    1    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    1     1
 [4,]    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0     1
 [5,]    1    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    1     1
 [6,]    1    1    1    1    0    1    0    1    0     1
 [7,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
 [8,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
 [9,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
[10,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
```

and if N=3

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    1    1    1    0    1    1    0    1    1     0
 [2,]    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0     1
 [3,]    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0     1
 [4,]    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [5,]    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0     1
 [6,]    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0     1
 [7,]    1    1    1    0    1    1    0    1    1     0
 [8,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
 [9,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
[10,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
```

I need the solution to cope with any sensible number of N steps. In practice N will be 8 or 10, and the matrices are around 8000x8000 in size.

The reason I need to do this is that the entries in these matrices are pixels from an image that I made binary (black and white). The zeros correspond to white lines and I want to "grow" the lines by N pixels (to represent imprecision of sampling in an analysis).

I need to do this in R, and in this "simple" way, so that all my images from different sources end up being processed in a consistent reproducible way.

I confess that the solution is beyond me, at least in a reasonable time frame, and so I am asking for help on this one. Image processors like GIMP do this all the time, so I am sure there is a solution.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You can use something like Flood fill algorithm; so basically you search for your zero and then find nearby cells that need to be 0 and update them;https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill

Comment: I don't understand why a path can't be a diagonal step followed by, e.g., a horizontal step. This makes it basically impossible to use a simple recursive approach. What is the logic behind this?

Comment: apologies Roland, yes a path can be diagonal then horizontal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that turns the eight neighbors to zero in a single step and does the following steps by recursion.

```
M <- matrix(1, ncol = 10, nrow = 10)
M[4, 7] <- 0
M[10, 1] <- 0

set0 <- function(M, n) {
  
  stopifnot("invalid n" = is.numeric(n) & n > 0)
  n <- ceiling(n)
  
  #recursion
  if (n > 1L) return(set0(set0(M, n - 1L), 1L))
  
  #find zeros
  zeros <- which(M == 0, arr.ind = TRUE)
  
  #loop over zeros
  for (i in seq_len(nrow(zeros))) {

    #the eight neighbors
    x <- zeros[i,1] + c(-1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)
    y <- zeros[i,2] + c(-1, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1, 0, 1)
    
    #check for out of matrix
    remx <- x < 1 | x > ncol(M)
    remy <- y < 1 | y > nrow(M)
    
    ind <- cbind(x, y)
    ind[remx,] <- NA
    ind[remy,] <- NA
    
    ind <- na.omit(ind)
    
    #set to zero
    M[ind] <- 0
  }
  M
}

M
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
# [2,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
# [3,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
# [4,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    0    1    1     1
# [5,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
# [6,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
# [7,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
# [8,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
# [9,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
#[10,]    0    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1

set0(M, 1L)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
# [2,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
# [3,]    1    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    1     1
# [4,]    1    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    1     1
# [5,]    1    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    1     1
# [6,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
# [7,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
# [8,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
# [9,]    0    0    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
#[10,]    0    0    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1

set0(M, 2L)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
# [2,]    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0     1
# [3,]    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0     1
# [4,]    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0     1
# [5,]    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0     1
# [6,]    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0     1
# [7,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
# [8,]    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
# [9,]    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
#[10,]    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
```

**Edit:**

A faster version without the loop:

```
set0 <- function(M, n) {
  
  stopifnot("invalid n" = is.numeric(n) & n > 0)
  n <- ceiling(n)
  
  #recursion
  if (n > 1L) return(set0(set0(M, n - 1L), 1L))
  
  #find zeros
  zeros <- which(M == 0, arr.ind = TRUE)
  zeros <- do.call(cbind, rep(list(zeros), 8))
  zeros <- array(zeros, c(nrow(zeros), 2, 8))
  
  step <- cbind(c(-1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1),
                      c(-1, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1, 0, 1))
  step <- do.call(cbind, rep(list(step), nrow(zeros)))
  step <- array(step, c(8, 2, nrow(zeros)))
  step <- aperm(step, c(3, 2, 1))
  
  zeros <- zeros + step

  #check for out of matrix
  zeros[,1,][zeros[,1,] < 1 | zeros[,1,] > ncol(M)] <- NA
  zeros[,2,][zeros[,2,] < 1 | zeros[,2,] > nrow(M)] <- NA

  zeros <- aperm(zeros, c(1, 3, 2))
  zeros <- matrix(zeros, ncol = 2)
  zeros <- na.omit(zeros)
  
  M[zeros] <- 0
  M
}
```

Comment: The faster version without the loop completed in a few minutes on my large matrices, while the other solutions, including those by other authors (to date), took several hours to run. The first solution by KSkoczek was also fast, but could have problems near matrix edges with some data.

Answer (score 1):

For low N this can be done with some loops but would also require some logic to cover cases where 0s are within N of an edge. This code fills a central square then an additional cell in the main meridians, which works exactly for N=2 and 3 as above.

```
    #Make our data
Data <- matrix(1, nrow=10, ncol=10)
Data[4,7]<-0

#set N
N=2

#Determine where the 0s are
Zeros = Data==0
ZeroIndex=which(Zeros, arr.ind=T)

#Make output matrix

DataOut=Data

for (p in 1:sum(Zeros)){ #Per 0 point
  
  Point=ZeroIndex[p,] #Get the indices of each point
  
  #Transform central square
  DataOut[(Point[1]-(N-1)):(Point[1]+(N-1)),(Point[2]-(N-1)):(Point[2]+(N-1))] <- 0
  
  #Transform outer points in main meridians
   DataOut[Point[1]-N, Point[2]] <- 0
   DataOut[Point[1]+N, Point[2]] <- 0
   DataOut[Point[1], Point[2]-N] <- 0
   DataOut[Point[1], Point[2]+N] <- 0
  
    DataOut[Point[1]-N, Point[2]-N] <- 0
    DataOut[Point[1]-N, Point[2]+N] <- 0
    DataOut[Point[1]+N, Point[2]-N] <- 0
    DataOut[Point[1]+N, Point[2]+N] <- 0
  
}

Data
DataOut
```

For bigger N this will lose some fidelity at the edges but might be along the right lines (I expect altering the lines referencing N-1 will be the route to take)

Hope it helps, still something of a beginner to R so welcome to criticism/additions.

EDIT: Re-read the post and the line about L-shaped paths inspired this alternative which I suspect may work better for larger N. Again, edge detecting logic is probably needed.

```
#Make our data
Data <- matrix(1, nrow=10, ncol=10)
Data[4,7]<-0

#set N
N=3

#Determine where the 0s are
Zeros = Data==0
ZeroIndex=which(Zeros, arr.ind=T)

#Make output matrix

DataOut=Data

for (p in 1:sum(Zeros)){ #Per 0 point
  
  Point=ZeroIndex[p,] #Get the indices of each point
  
  #Transform outer points in main meridians
  DataOut[Point[1]-N, Point[2]] <- 0
  DataOut[Point[1]+N, Point[2]] <- 0
  DataOut[Point[1], Point[2]-N] <- 0
  DataOut[Point[1], Point[2]+N] <- 0
  
  DataOut[Point[1]-N, Point[2]-N] <- 0
  DataOut[Point[1]-N, Point[2]+N] <- 0
  DataOut[Point[1]+N, Point[2]-N] <- 0
  DataOut[Point[1]+N, Point[2]+N] <- 0
  
  for (n in 1:N){ 
    
    #Transform straight paths
    DataOut[Point[1], Point[2]-n] <- 0
    DataOut[Point[1], Point[2]+n] <- 0
    DataOut[Point[1]+n, Point[2]] <- 0
    DataOut[Point[1]-n, Point[2]] <- 0
    
    DataOut[Point[1]-n, Point[2]-n] <- 0
    DataOut[Point[1]+n, Point[2]+n] <- 0
    DataOut[Point[1]+n, Point[2]-n] <- 0
    DataOut[Point[1]-n, Point[2]+n] <- 0
    
    #Transform L shaped paths
    for (x in 1:n){ 
      y=n-x
      
      DataOut[Point[1]-y, Point[2]+x] <- 0
      DataOut[Point[1]+y, Point[2]-x] <- 0
      DataOut[Point[1]-y, Point[2]-x] <- 0
      DataOut[Point[1]+y, Point[2]+x] <- 0
      
    } #close x loop
    
    for (y in 1:n){
      x=n-y
      
      DataOut[Point[1]-y, Point[2]+x] <- 0
      DataOut[Point[1]+y, Point[2]-x] <- 0
      DataOut[Point[1]-y, Point[2]-x] <- 0
      DataOut[Point[1]+y, Point[2]+x] <- 0
      
    } #close y loop
    
  } #close n loop
  
}# closep loop

Data
DataOut
```

Comment: Thank you, I tested this solution on the real data and it did get the job done (I don't have zeroes within N of the matrix boundaries), so that's a good fast answer for an R beginner! I haven't clicked this as "solved" just yet though because it's only fair to give other time zoners a look too, for a general solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fully working solution that plays nicely at the edges. It makes use of `expand.grid` to get the positions, as well as taking advantage of array indexing:

```r
get_moves <- function(n) {
  df <- expand.grid(x = seq(n + 1) - 1, y = seq(n + 1) - 1)
  df <- df[rowSums(df) <= n,]
  `rownames<-`(as.matrix(setNames(unique(rbind(df, 
        within(df, x <- -x), 
        within(df, y <- -y),
        within(df, {y<- -y; x <- -x}))), c("row", "col"))), NULL)
}

zero_indices <- function(mat, rownum, colnum, n)
{
  indices <- get_moves(n)
  indices[, 1] <- indices[, 1] + rownum
  indices[, 2] <- indices[, 2] + colnum

  indices <- indices[indices[, 1] >= 1, ]
  indices <- indices[indices[, 2] >= 1, ]
  indices <- indices[indices[, 2] <= ncol(mat), ]
  indices[indices[, 1] <= nrow(mat), ]
  indices
}

replace_zeros <- function(mat, n)
{
  z <- which(mat == 0, arr.ind = TRUE)
  mat[do.call(rbind, lapply(seq(nrow(z)), function(i) {
    zero_indices(mat, z[i,1], z[i,2], n)}))] <- 0
  mat
}
```

So let's test it on a sample 10 x 10 matrix:

```
mat <- matrix(1, nrow = 10, ncol = 10)
mat[3, 3] <- 0
mat[7, 8] <- 0

mat
#>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#>  [1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
#>  [2,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
#>  [3,]    1    1    0    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
#>  [4,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
#>  [5,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
#>  [6,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
#>  [7,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    0    1     1
#>  [8,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
#>  [9,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
#> [10,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
```

With n = 2 we get

```
replace_zeros(mat, 2)
#>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#>  [1,]    1    1    0    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
#>  [2,]    1    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    1     1
#>  [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1     1
#>  [4,]    1    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    1     1
#>  [5,]    1    1    0    1    1    1    1    0    1     1
#>  [6,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    0    0    0     1
#>  [7,]    1    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    0     0
#>  [8,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    0    0    0     1
#>  [9,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    0    1     1
#> [10,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
```

and with n = 3 we get:

```r
replace_zeros(mat, 3)
#>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#>  [1,]    1    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    1     1
#>  [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1     1
#>  [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1     1
#>  [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    1     1
#>  [5,]    1    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    0     1
#>  [6,]    1    1    0    1    1    0    0    0    0     0
#>  [7,]    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0     0
#>  [8,]    1    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    0     0
#>  [9,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    0    0    0     1
#> [10,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    0    1     1
```

I suspect there are faster implementations possible, but this strikes a reasonable balance between speed and complexity.